# best way to get list of all javascript files loaded on entire website

Tags: javascript, security, web-scraping

What's the best way to get a list of all Javascript files loaded on an entire website, not 1 specific page? I'm thinking a spider would be needed but haven't been able to find one that delivers what I'm looking for. This would be for security auditing purposes. Thanks!

Comment: this is recently more complicated thanks to imports. Before that, and largely still today, all scripts come in through the DOM, so if you can find all the script tags (hard-coded and dynamic), you can find all the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to index a starting point for your webpage, like the home page for example, for links to other HTML files. You can make AJAX requests to the files found, and index those, etc. This will work as long as you are always requesting files that end in `.html` and you are not relying on JavaScript redirects, `window.location.href = "https://website..."`.

You will then need to index each of the collected URLs for JS files:

If you are not using modules, you can use:

```js
const scriptURLs = [...document.getElementsByTagNames("script")].map(element => element.src);
```

But if you are using modules, you can make AJAX requests to the initial JS file, make a program to process it for other imported scripts, and follow the tree of modules. This is made even more difficult if you have dynamically imported modules, `import("./file.js")`.

Comment: *"on an entire website, not 1 specific page"*. Your answer is page specific

Comment: @charlietfl Fixed it.

Comment: @luekbaja thanks for the input but like charlietfl said that solution seems page specific and I'm looking for a site wide solution. Something like: input domain name, spider crawls fetched xml sitemap and returns a de-duped list of urls to the javascript files that were loaded and on which pages.